# joomla user profile and user photo gallery

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I am wondering if anyone knows whether there exists an extension to:

1. Add a profile for each registered user (editable by them)
2. Add allow registered users to add their own photo gallery

Comment: not really a coding problem....search the JED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For advanced profile editing, you would be best off using an extension such as [Community Builder](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/communities/210). It allows you to create custom fields for registration and profile editing. As for the Photo Gallery, you would probably be best off searching for one on [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/galleries/photo-gallery) as there are a few but some have different features, so it will be better if you choose something that suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This extension may seems to fullfill much of your requirements -
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/communities/10997